# Power BI service and app

Tags: database, data-visualization, powerbi

I have created multiple reports and dashboard for a organisation using Power BI using SQL connection(Microsoft AX database), Now I want to re-use these reports for a different organisation having the same AX database.Is there a way to bundle up these reports and change the Database credentials for once and get it done? Can it be done using Power BI app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to download the Power Bi pbix from the online service. From here you can edit the credentials for the data source but going to:

File > Options and Settings > Data Source Settings > Edit Permissions > Edit

You would then need to sign in with the account linked with the other organisation. You can do this by going to the top right of Power Bi desktop and switching the user account.

Publishing the report should now publish to the new organisation, data should refresh as normal as long as appropriate infrastructure is in place (i.e. if it's on-premises data then you would also need to setup a data gateway within the organisation)

Thanks,
J